# How can i install flash builder 4.7 in Eclipse X64 folder(dropins) (version 4.6) its impossible?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

- (in my Eclipse 4.6 X64 eclipseproduct :
     name=Eclipse Platform
     id=org.eclipse.platform
     version=3.7.0

  And i'm using flash builder 4.7

  Thank you guys .)

Comment: why? flash builder is an instance of eclipse, its not plugin, install it in a separate location

Comment: Hello . it has a plugin in utilities folder named as (Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Plug-in Utility.exe) and prevent me to complete installation because of Version ...

Comment: And also i want to work whit one IDE like intelliJ instead of several program

Comment: about intelliJ, is it really possible to mixing for example androidstudio and phpstorm in single instance of intelliJ IDE o_O !? you may want to try again what you did with flash builder 4.6 instead, but i guess you get no success too

Comment: I know its possible using flash builder plugin in eclipse

Comment: I know its possible using flash builder plugin in eclipse And also use adobe/Apache  flex in intelliJ IDE same as java. I just to try using one ide

Comment: @Mohammadtavakoly I hope soon one IDE will be Visual Studio Code with extension [vscode-nextgenas](https://github.com/BowlerHatLLC/vscode-nextgenas)

Comment: Thank you i hope to . but too late :}